# VBA Copy Region & Insert X Rows Based on Region

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to copy a section of data and insert X amount of rows based on the current region and paste with it's values only into the newly created rows that push down multiple sub tables below this data.

What I have currently is trying to copy the cells data except the header row but it still does so.
An array of worksheets, this copy insert paste should work on. However, on certain sheets the code isn't doing as expected since the data pastes repeatedly  to the end of columns; so it's a whole row of data pasted across but does not happen on all sheets.

It works mostly expect the said errors and because the copied region are formulas, the data doesn't paste itself correctly, I only want the values being pasted.

```
Dim lrow, lcol, brow, row, iRange, i As Long
Dim arrWs As Variant
Dim dRange, fcell, cRange As Range
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & eStrFile)

Const first_cell As String = "A2"

arrWs = Array(7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 15)

For i = LBound(arrWs) To UBound(arrWs)
    
    With wb.Sheets(arrWs(i))
    
        Set fcell = .Range(first_cell)
        
        Set cRange = fcell.CurrentRegion.Resize(.Rows.Count - fcell.row)
        iRange = fcell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + cRange.row + 1
    
        cRange.CurrentRegion.Copy
        .Rows(iRange).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Are the headers on row 1, or row 2?

Comment: @TimWilliams row 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear on exactly what you're trying to do, but this should be close:

```
    Dim arrWs As Variant, wb As Workbook, i As Long, rng As Range
    '...
    '...
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & eStrFile)
    
    arrWs = Array(7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 15)
    
    For i = LBound(arrWs) To UBound(arrWs)
        Set rng = wb.Sheets(arrWs(i)).Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'includes headers
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1) 'exclude headers and resize
        
        rng.Offset(rng.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlShiftDown 'insert rows below
        rng.Offset(rng.Rows.Count).Value = rng.Value                   'copy values only
    Next i
```